select list option value arrays don't map to c# object
Class structure:
public class MergedActivity{
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public string Type {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class FormModel{
   public SelectList MergedActivitiesSelect {get;set;}
   public ICollection<MergedActivity> MergedActivitiesSearch {get;set;}
}

MergedActivitiesSelect set in controller:
var model = new FormModel();
model.MergedActivitiesSelect = new SelectList(mergedactivites.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem
{
    Value = "{\"value\":"+x.Value.ToString()+", \"type\":\""+x.Type+"\"}",
    Text=x.Name
}).ToList(), "Value", "Text", model.MergedActivitiesSearch);      

Form page:
<form name="searchform" id="searchform" >
  <div class="form-group">
   @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.MergedActivitiesSearch, Model.MergedActivitiesSelected, new
    {
        @data_actions_box = "true",
        @class = "selectpicker",
        @title = "-Select Merged Activities-",
        multiple = "true",
        @data_live_search = "true",
        @data_selected_text_format = "count > 3",
        @data_width = "100%"
    })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Search</button>  
</form>

Here is an example of an option value:
{&quot;value&quot;:18, &quot;type&quot;:&quot;Event&quot;}
{"value":18,"type":"Event"}

For form submission, it is passed as a serialized object.
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="searchform"]', function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: app.search,
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#searchform").serialize()
    })
})

After selected a couple and submitting the form, the model FormModel MergedActivitiesSearch is still empty .  Is the value array incorrect?  Is there something wrong with serialize into objects?
